# Visual Studio Code/Jupyter: Rendering to HTML breaks Markdown table

Tags: visual-studio-code, jupyter-notebook, jupyter

I am using the Jupyter extension in VSCode to write a Python notebook. In it, I have this Markdown cell:

```
|Column|Range|Average|
|---|---|---|
|mpg|37.6|23.445918|
|weight|3527|2977.584184|
|year|12|76.010256|
```

When exporting to HTML, it renders as a paragraph rather than a table element:

|Column|Range|Average| |---|---|---| |mpg|37.6|23.445918| |weight|3527|2977.584184| |year|12|76.010256|

I don't see any issues with my syntax, and in fact the table renders correctly when exporting directly to pdf via Latex. What could be causing the issue?